# Exact Match SQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a SQL query problem with the results of some PHP string stripping:

I am querying a field based on a partial postcode.  This is failing because it is matching search terms 'S5' as a partial match to 'HS5'.

The search term can be either S5 or HS5 but I only want to match HS5.

My code looks like this:

```
$customer_postcode ='S5 9PO';
//strip anything after the space in a postcode
$customer_postcode = substr($customer_order_postcode, 0, strrpos($customer_order_postcode, ' '));


$islands_postcodes = 'HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42,IV43,IV44,IV45,IV46,IV48,V49,IV51,IV55,IV56,KA27,KA28,KW15,KW16,KW17,PA20,PA41,PA42,PA43,PA44,PA45,PA46,PA47,PA48,PA49,PA60,PA61,PA62,PA63,PA64,PA65,PA66,PA67,PA68,PA69,PA70,PA71,PA72,PA73,PA74,PA75,PA76,PA77,PA78,PH41,PH42,PH43,PF44,ZE1,ZE2,ZE3,IM,GY,JE';

$search_highlands = strpos($highland_postcodes, $customer_postcode);

if($search_highlands==true) $country = $customer_postcode;

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shipping_rules WHERE country_string LIKE '%$country%'");
```

Comment: Not sure, but you may be looking for a whole word match `$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shipping_rules WHERE country_string REGEXP '[[:<:]]$country[[:>:]]'");`

Comment: `list($left, $right) = explode(' ', $customer_postcode);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `%` like this

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shipping_rules WHERE country_string LIKE '$country'");
```

Or don't use `like` Try like this

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shipping_rules WHERE country_string= '$country'");
```

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to mention that $islands_postcodes IS the single value of 'country_string' in the SQL

Answer (score 1):

Take care, there a number of errors in the code.

Anyway, if you do:

```
$customer_order_postcode ='S5 9PO';
//strip anything after the space in a postcode
$customer_postcode = substr($customer_order_postcode, 0, strrpos($customer_order_postcode, ' '));

$islands_postcodes = 'HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42,IV43,IV44,IV45,IV46,IV48,V49,IV51,IV55,IV56,KA27,KA28,KW15,KW16,KW17,PA20,PA41,PA42,PA43,PA44,PA45,PA46,PA47,PA48,PA49,PA60,PA61,PA62,PA63,PA64,PA65,PA66,PA67,PA68,PA69,PA70,PA71,PA72,PA73,PA74,PA75,PA76,PA77,PA78,PH41,PH42,PH43,PF44,ZE1,ZE2,ZE3,IM,GY,JE';

$search_highlands = strpos($islands_postcodes, $customer_postcode);

if($search_highlands==true) $country = $customer_postcode;

print($country);
```

you see that:

```
$country = 'S5'
```

as a consequence of how you calculated $customer_postcode.

You have to design a different strategy to extract full postcode from  $islands_postcodes or simply do:

```
$customer_order_postcode ='S5 9PO';
//strip anything after the space in a postcode
$customer_postcode = substr($customer_order_postcode, 0, strrpos($customer_order_postcode, ' '));

$islands_postcodes = 'HS1,HS2,HS3,HS4,HS5,HS6,HS7,HS8,HS9,IV41,IV42,IV43,IV44,IV45,IV46,IV48,V49,IV51,IV55,IV56,KA27,KA28,KW15,KW16,KW17,PA20,PA41,PA42,PA43,PA44,PA45,PA46,PA47,PA48,PA49,PA60,PA61,PA62,PA63,PA64,PA65,PA66,PA67,PA68,PA69,PA70,PA71,PA72,PA73,PA74,PA75,PA76,PA77,PA78,PH41,PH42,PH43,PF44,ZE1,ZE2,ZE3,IM,GY,JE';

$search_highlands = strpos($islands_postcodes, $customer_postcode);

if($search_highlands==true) $country = 'H'.$customer_postcode;

print($country);
```

Regards